# Как найти период десятичной дроби 1/n

Tags: python, list, список

На вводе дается одно число **n**
Нужно вывести период десятичной дроби **1/n**
Пример:

```
input: 11
output: 09

input: 13
output: 076923

input: 101
output: 0099
```

Я уже что не перебровал, но проблемы начинаются, когда в периоде повторяются одинаковые числа вместе (0099). Есть какая нибудь формула, метод, алгоритм по нахождению такового? А то я уже все пересмотрел, не нашёл.
**По условию необходимо решение без функция и навороченных методов со списками и т.д.**

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_period(n, d):
    z = x = n * 9
    k = 1
    while z % d:
        z = z * 10 + x
        k += 1

    digits = f"{z // d:0{k}}"
    return k, digits

# Test

num, den = 1, 7
period, digits = find_period(num, den)
print('num:', num, 'den:', den, 'period:', period, 'digits:', digits)

num, den = 1, 17
period, digits = find_period(num, den)
print('num:', num, 'den:', den, 'period:', period, 'digits:', digits)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52383948/calculate-period-length-of-recurring-decimal-fraction

Comment: А как можно без функций?

Comment: Вынести код из функции в тело программы)