# Как найти период дроби 1/N?

Tags: c, алгоритм

Вот примеры ввода и вывода:

input: 3
output: 3

input: 5
output: 0

input: 7
output: 142857

Comment: Так проблема с Си или с алгоритмом?

Comment: есть правило, что что период дроби не будет больше самого N. А это сильно упрощает задачу

Comment: Уже задавали [Как найти период десятичной дроби 1/n](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1064719/Как-найти-период-десятичной-дроби-1-n), но дубликатом это пометить нельзя - ответ не принят и за него не проголосовали. Ну и там на python, достаточно, чтобы ухватиться за идею. Вдруг поможет.

Comment: @andreymal, проблема все же с алгоритмом. Были разные идеи, но ни одной не смог реализовать для решения

Comment: @mrEvgenX, написанное на Питоне, слишком отличается от реализации на Си. Видел его, но оно никак не помогло

Comment: @KoVadim, период дроби всегда меньше N - различных остатков от деления на N ровно N.

Answer (score 5):

Есть интересный алгоритм, я использовал его для поиска циклов. Не использует дополнительную память, скорость **O(N)**. Никаких квадратичных сложностей при больших числах. Как посоветовал [Stanislav Volodarskiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/416121/stanislav-volodarskiy) можно найти первоначальную точку входа в цикл *(если надо)*.

```
// gcc -Wall -Wextra period.c -o period && ./period
# include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  unsigned  int const arr [ ] = {2,3,11,13,14,17,19,23};
  for ( unsigned int const * i = arr ;i < * ( ( & arr ) + 1 ) ;++i){
    unsigned  int n = *i ;
    printf ("1/%u = ",n);
    unsigned  int n10 = 1U ;
    unsigned  int n100  = 1U ;
    // I. ищем факт цикла
    do {
      n10 = ( n10 * 10U ) % n ;
      // ( ( ( n100 * 10U ) % n ) * 10U ) % n == ( n100 * 100U ) % n
      n100 = ( n100 * 100U ) % n ;
      if ( n100 == 0U ) {
        printf("0");
        goto cont ; }
    } while ( n10 != n100 ) ;
    // II. проходим число с начала на дистанцию
    //   размера цикла ( опционально )
    n100 = 1U ;
    { unsigned  int nstart  = n10 ;
      do {
        n10 = ( n10 * 10 ) % n ;
        n100 = ( n100 * 10 ) % n ;
      } while ( n10 != nstart ) ; }
    // III. Ищем первоначальную точку входа в цикл
    // ( опционально )
    n10 = 1U ;
    while ( n10 !=  n100  ) {
      n10 = ( n10 * 10 ) % n ;
      n100  = ( n100  * 10 ) % n ; }
    // IV. Печатаем
    { unsigned  int nstart  = n10 ;
      do {
        printf("%u",(n10 * 10) / n);
        n10 = ( n10 * 10 ) % n ;
      } while ( n10 != nstart ) ; }
cont :
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

результат :

```
1/2 = 0
1/3 = 3
1/11 = 09
1/13 = 076923
1/14 = 714285
1/17 = 0588235294117647
1/19 = 052631578947368421
1/23 = 0434782608695652173913
```

Comment: Так прелесть именно в том, что буфера нет и указателя тоже. Пока ещё я не нашёл пример неправильного входа в цикл. Да и вопросе не было сказано как показывать зацикленную последовательность. @Stanislav Volodarskiy

Comment: Неверно считает такие случаи, как 1/22, 1/2222 и т.д. Все приводит к тому, что если начинаю фиксить одно - слетает то, что уже было верно...

Comment: у меня показывает `1/22 = 45` , а калькулятор = `0.0454545...` А что тут неверно ?

Answer (score 3):

Задача состоит из двух частей. Сначала нужно найти длину периода, затем вычислить периодическую часть дроби `2^a / n` или `5^a / n`.

Вычисление длины периода описал @Mbo. Сначала убираем из `n` все делители, кратные 2 и 5, затем перебором ищем такое `N`, что `10^N mod n == 1`.

```
typedef struct {
    int n;  // Приведённое число
    int pwr2; // Степень двойки в исходном числе
    int pwr5; // Степень пятёрки в исходном числе
} strip_2_5_res_t;

// Приведение числа.
// Возвращает число, полученное из n делением на число, кратное 2 и 5, 
// а также степени 2 5 в исходном числе.
strip_2_5_res_t strip_2_5(int n) {
    strip_2_5_res_t result = {0,0,0};

    if (n == 0) { return result; }

    if (n < 0) { n = -n; }

    while (n % 2 == 0) {
        n /= 2;
        result.pwr2++;
    }
    while (n % 5 == 0) {
        n /= 5;
        result.pwr5++;
    }
    result.n = n;
    return result;
}

// Возвращает длину периода.
// "Период дроби" переводится как "repetend", поэтому функция называется repetend_len
// Число n должно быть приведено!
int repetend_len(int n) {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
        return 0;
    }

    int l = 0;
    int q = 10;
    l = 1;
    while (q%n != 1) {
        l++;
        q = (10*q) % n;
    }
    return l;
}
```

Вторая часть - вычисление собственно периода.

Если число `n` не делится ни на 2, ни на 5, то всё просто. Для этого достаточно возвести 10 в степень `p` (длина периода), вычесть единичку и поделить на `n`.

Чуть хитрее дело обстоит с числами, которые кратны 2 или 5. Представим их как произведение степени 10, поделённой на степень 2 или 5, и приведённого числа.
Например, `60 = (10^2 / 5^1) * 3`, а `350 = (10^2 / 2^1) * 7`
Другими словами, `n = (10^x / factor) * n_reduced`,
где `factor` или равен единице, или делится либо только на 2, либо только на 5, а `n_reduced` - это приведённое число.
Тогда периодом дроби `1/n` будет период дроби `factor/n_reduced` - множитель `10^x` всего лишь добавит нулей в начало записи дроби.

Например, у дроби `1/60` период совпадает с периодом дроби `5/3`, а у дроби `1/350` с периодом дроби `2/7`. То есть период равен
`factor*(10^p - 1) / n_reduced`
Здесь `p` - длина периода.

Основная хитрость в том, что для вычисления периода целочисленной арифметикой пользоваться нельзя. Даже у сравнительно небольших `n` период дроби может оказаться гораздо больше 64-х. Первое такое число 97, у него период дроби равен 96. Понятное дело, `10^96-1` не влезет в 64-х битный `long long`. Даже если вы возьмёте 128-битную арифметику, то легко найти пример, который в неё не влезет. Например, у дроби `1/65537` длина периода равна 65536.

*Лирическое замечание. Длина периода является одним из делителей числа `fi(n)`, где `fi` - функция Эйлера. Если n - простое число, то длина периода может оказаться равной n-1. В первой сотне таких чисел 9: 7, 17, 19, 23, 29, 47, 59, 61, 97.*

Поэтому делить нужно столбиком, результат возвращать в виде строки.

```
// Для malloc
#include <stdlib.h>

// Возвращает дробную часть числа m/n.
// Предполагается, что число n уже приведено, и вычислен период дроби.
// Предполагается, что n > 1, m > 0.
// Возвращается указатель на строку, аллоцированную в куче. Строку необходимо free после использования.
char* m_div_n_frac(int m, int n, int len) {
    char * result;
    int q0 = m%n;
    int q = q0;
    int i = 0;

    result = malloc(len+1);
    while (i < len) {
        int digit = (q*10) / n;
        result[i++] = digit + '0';
        q = (q*10) % n;
        if (q == q0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    result[i] = '\0';
    return result;
}
```

Теперь, имея на руках функции для вычисления длины периода, и функцию деления столбиком, можно вычислить период.

```
// Возвращает период дробной части числа 1/n.
// Возвращается указатель на строку, аллоцированную в куче. Строку необходимо free после использования.
char * repetend(int n) {
    strip_2_5_res_t r = strip_2_5(n);

    int m = r.n;
    int l = repetend_len(m);
    
    if (l == 0) {
        char * result = malloc(2);
        result[0] = '0';
        result[1] = '\0';
        return result;
    }

    int maxpwr = (r.pwr2 > r.pwr5) ? r.pwr2 : r.pwr5;
    int factor = 1;
    for (int i = r.pwr2; i < maxpwr; i++) { factor *= 2; }
    for (int i = r.pwr5; i < maxpwr; i++) { factor *= 5; }

    return m_div_n_frac(factor, m, l);
}
```

Для тестирования я использовал вот такой `main`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// Для strlen
#include <string.h>

void report(int n) {
    char * result = repetend(n);
    int l = strlen(result);
    // Если дробь конечная, то для неё возвращается строка "0"
    if (l == 1 && result[0] == '0') { l = 0; }

    printf("N: %d, repetend length: %d, repetend: '%s'\n", n, l, result);
    free(result);
}

int main(int arc, char ** argv) {
    report(60);
    report(350);
    report(2);
    report(3);
    report(4);
    report(5);
    report(6);
    report(7);
    report(8);
    report(9);
    report(11);
    report(13);
    report(15);
    report(17);
    report(19);
    report(97);
    report(12321);
    // Если хотите посмотреть на дробь длиной 65536 знаков, раскомментируйте
    // report(65537);
}
```

Результат таков:

```
N: 60, repetend length: 1, repetend: '6'
N: 350, repetend length: 6, repetend: '285714'
N: 2, repetend length: 0, repetend: '0'
N: 3, repetend length: 1, repetend: '3'
N: 4, repetend length: 0, repetend: '0'
N: 5, repetend length: 0, repetend: '0'
N: 6, repetend length: 1, repetend: '6'
N: 7, repetend length: 6, repetend: '142857'
N: 8, repetend length: 0, repetend: '0'
N: 9, repetend length: 1, repetend: '1'
N: 11, repetend length: 2, repetend: '09'
N: 13, repetend length: 6, repetend: '076923'
N: 15, repetend length: 1, repetend: '6'
N: 17, repetend length: 16, repetend: '0588235294117647'
N: 19, repetend length: 18, repetend: '052631578947368421'
N: 97, repetend length: 96, repetend: '010309278350515463917525773195876288659793814432989690721649484536082474226804123711340206185567'
N: 12321, repetend length: 111, repetend: '000081162243324405486567648729810891973054135216297378459540621702783864946027108189270351432513594675756837919'
```

Answer (score 3):

Так как решение на C, желательно сделать его оптимальным по скорости и по памяти. Ещё нужно принять во внимание ограниченность целого типа. К счастью, задача хорошо соответствует выразительным способностям языка.

Хотя в вопросе просили печатать цикл дроби `1/n`, здесь показано как полностью напечатать любую дробь вида `m/n`. Объём вычислений и сложность решения почти одинаковы для обеих задач.

В дальнейшем знак `//` обозначает деление нацело.

Целая часть числа равна `m // n`. Остаток от деления `r = m % n` образует правильную дробь `r/n` - дробную часть.

Алгоритм печати дробной части основан на школьном алгоритме деления.

В цикле печатаем цифры дробной части: очередная цифра `d = 10 * r // n`, очередной остаток `r = 10 * r % n`.

Дробная часть состоит из префикса и цикла. Префикс может быть любой длины, может быть и пустым. Цикл всегда не пустой - даже если дробь конечная, цикл - цепочка из нулей.

Цикл отыскивается [алгоритмом Флойда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0#%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0_%D0%B8_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%86): черепаха шагает на одну цифру, заяц скачет на две. Когда остатки у черепахи и зайца совпали, мы в цикле.

Для определения длины цикла стартуем с найденного остатка из цикла, считаем шаги до получения того же остатка.

Чтобы отыскать начало цикла одну черепаху ставим в начало дроби, вторую продвигаем вперед на длину цикла. Черепахи шагают на один шаг синхронно. Первое совпадение остатков означает что первая черепаха в начале цикла.

Зная длину префикса (совпадает с началом цикла) и длину цикла можно напечатать дробь в формате `69/28 = 2.46(428571)`.

Алгоритм не использует длинную арифметику и работает в константной памяти. Время работы пропорционально размеру результата. Константу можно улучшить, но уже в ущерб простоте решения. Знаменатель должен без переполнения умножаться на 10.

```
// gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 print-fraction.c

#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// отыскивает какой-нибудь остаток из циклической части правильной дроби m/n
long reminder_in_loop(long m, long n) {
    assert(m < n);

    // алгоритм Флойда: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0#%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0_%D0%B8_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%86
    // когда оба остатка попадут на цикл и расстояние станет кратно длине цикла, остатки совпадут
    long r1 = m;
    long r2 = m;
    for (; ; ) {
        r1 = 10 * r1 % n;
        // тоже самое что и 100 * r2 % n, но реже переполняется
        r2 = 10 * (10 * r2 % n) % n;
        if (r1 == r2) {
            return r1;
        }
    }
}

// вычисляет длину циклической части правильной дроби m/n
long loop_length(long m, long n) {
    // любой остаток из циклической части
    long r1 = reminder_in_loop(m, n);

    // бежим дальше, считаем шаги до момента когда остаток повторится
    long r2 = r1;
    for (long i = 1; ; ++i) {
        r2 = 10 * r2 % n;
        if (r2 == r1) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}

// вычисляет начало циклической части правильной дроби m/n
// ll должно быть равно loop_length(m, n)
long loop_start(long m, long n, long ll) {
    long r1 = m;

    // отступаем на длину цикла
    long r2 = m;
    for (long i = 0; i < ll; ++i) {
        r2 = 10 * r2 % n;
    }

    // синхронно сдвигаем остатки, считаем шаги до момента когда они совпадут
    for (long i = 0; ; ++i) {
        if (r1 == r2) {
            return i;
        }
        r1 = 10 * r1 % n;
        r2 = 10 * r2 % n;
    }
}

// печатает n_digits цифр правильной дроби m/n
// возвращает остаток для продолжения печати дроби
long print_digits(FILE *f, long m, long n, long n_digits) {
    long r = m;
    for (long i = 0; i < n_digits; ++i) {
        fprintf(f, "%ld", 10 * r / n);
        r = 10 * r % n;
    }
    return r;
}

// печатает дробь m/n
void print_decimal_fraction(FILE *f, long m, long n) {
    // печатаем целую часть
    fprintf(f, "%ld", m / n);

    // получаем правильную дробь r/n
    long r = m % n;

    // печатаем дробную часть
    if (r != 0) {
        fputc('.', f);

        // параметры цикла - длина и начало
        long ll = loop_length(r, n);
        long ls = loop_start(r, n, ll);

        // печатаем цифры дробной части до начала цикла
        r = print_digits(f, r, n, ls);

        // печатаем цифры цикла в скобках
        if (r != 0) {
            fputc('(', f);
            print_digits(f, r, n, ll);
            fputc(')', f);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    assert(argc == 3);

    long m = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    long n = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10);

    assert(0 <= m);
    assert(n <= LONG_MAX / 10 + 1);

    print_decimal_fraction(stdout, m, n);

    puts("");
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 print-fraction.c
>
> $ ./a.out 1 3
> 0.(3)
>
> $ ./a.out 1 5
> 0.2
>
> $ ./a.out 1 7
> 0.(142857)
>
> $ ./a.out 41111 333000
> 0.123(456)
>
> $ ./a.out 1 9999943
> 0.(0000001000005700032...2233831732840877193)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Да алгоритм-то не слишком сложный.

Пока N делится на 2, делим на 2

Пока N делится на 5, делим на 5

Если получилось 1, период 0 - дробь непериодична.

Иначе у неё есть период `p`, и она может быть записана в виде (упрощённо, после точки ещё непериодичная часть может быть, пример для `p=6`)

```
 0.abcdefabcdefabcdef...
```

Если это умножить на `10^p`, то получится

```
abcdef.abcdefabcdefabcdef...  (точка после p цифр)
```

Если из второго вычесть первое, то получится целое abcdef

```
1/N * 10^p - 1/N = 1/N * (10^p-1)
```

Последнее   выражение - целое число, значит `(10^p-1)` делится на `N`

Вот и ищем такое `p`, чтобы `((10^p-1) % N) == 0`

Comment: Искать `p` без переполнения сложно.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function solve(n) {
  var used = Array(n)
  var res = []
  var x = 1
  
  for (var q=0; !used[x]; ++q) {
    used[x] = q
    res.push(x / n | 0)
    x %= n
    x *= 10
  }
  
  return res.slice(used[x]).join("")
}

console.log(solve(3))
console.log(solve(5))
console.log(solve(7))
console.log(solve(6))
console.log(solve(999999999))
```

Comment: Линейная память. :(

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, в условии нет ничего, что говорило бы, что так нельзя. В принципе, можно удвоить время, но не занимать память. UPDATE: Как ты и сделал)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, кстати, там не может использоваться слишком много памяти, потому что длина периода сравнима со знаменателем, а значит если там будет больше 10**6, то времени не хватит даже на вывод результата.